# How to redirect non existent pages/posts in wordpress using htaccess

Tags: redirect, htaccess, 404-error

How can I redirect non existent pages/posts in WordPress using only .htaccess file?

Here is my code:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^products/cool-tshirt$ /tshirts [R=301,L]

</IfModule>
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The `RewriteRule` directive above should already do what you require. If it's not working then you've probably put in in the wrong place - this redirect needs to go at the top of the `.htaccess` file, before the WordPress front-controller. If you are not using WP's permalinks (in which case you may not have WP front-controller in `.htaccess`) then make sure that mod_rewrite is enabled on your server.

Comment: You can just use one of redirection plug-ins. I use and like this one
https://wordpress.org/plugins/nomore404-404-redirection-and-firewall/ It not only does redirects, but can help you block bad guys too

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/products/cool-tshirt$ http://yourdomain.com/tshirts$1
```

You can also see a bunch of other options and solutions [here](http://forum.ait-pro.com/forums/topic/htaccess-redirect-code-where-do-i-add-redirect-htaccess-code/)

Hope this helps.

Comment: if you review my code you can see that I want to redirect `products/cool-tshirt` to `tshirts` when I use the above code it open 404 page.

Comment: Sorry I had misread the question. Edited my answer.

Comment: `redirect` alone doesn't work. It should be `RewriteRule`

Comment: Also see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11926237/redirecting-old-html-page-to-new-without-html-extension-page)

Comment: The `$1` at the end of the target URL is superfluous and should be removed. However, if you are already using WordPress permalinks (ie. you have existing mod_rewrite directives in `.htaccess`) then you should ideally use mod_rewrite (ie. `RewriteRule`) instead, in order to avoid potential conflicts. (Or, even better, use WordPress and avoid `.htaccess` altogether.)